# GLSL-like vector access in C

Tags: c, vector, macros, unions

In GLSL you can access the components of a vector using both names and indices, eg. if you have a `vec2 foo` then you can do do stuff like `foo.x` and `foo[0]`.

Is it possible to replicate this interface in C?

I currently have the following:

```
typedef union{
  struct{  float x1, x2;  };
  struct{  float  x,  y;  };
  float d[2];
}vec2;
```

which allows me to access the components of a `vec2 foo` like `foo.x` and `foo.d[0]`.

Is it possible to dispense of that nasty `.d`, arriving at `foo[0]`? (By any means, perhaps using some (even nastier) macro trickery?)

Comment: Probably impossible.

Comment: in C++ it is doable `~224 KByte` of code ([here _vec2<T> C++ template example for dvec2,ivec2,vec2,bvec2](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/6055/6868) ) However  C lacks the tools to do it (at least to my knowledge) and macros alone will not allow you all the combinations of access (or at least I do not see it). You are missing some coordinates there are `xyzw , rgba , stpq` for `vec4` and the access can be any like `yzx, xyw,wzy,xgq...` and constructors also combined too like `vec3(vec2,float),vec3(float,vec2),vec3(float,float,float),vec4(vec3,float),vec4(flaot,vec2,float)` ...

Comment: as you can see there are a lot of combinations to support all the `vec2/3/4` correctly. However I do not code in C (I am more C++ like coder) so I could be missing some stuff ...

Comment: @Spektre Yes, in C++ it seems intuitively possible, not least of all because you can overload the `[]` operator (I think I've seen it done before). Thanks for the reference, too!

Comment: @étale-cohomology the code in the link is missing just the final touch: `typedef _vec2<float >  vec2; typedef _vec3<float >  vec3; typedef _vec4<float >  vec4;
typedef _vec2<double> dvec2; typedef _vec3<double> dvec3; typedef _vec4<double> dvec4;
typedef _vec2<bool  > bvec2; typedef _vec3<bool  > bvec3; typedef _vec4<bool  > bvec4;
typedef _vec2<int   > ivec2; typedef _vec3<int   > ivec3; typedef _vec4<int   > ivec4;
typedef _vec2<DWORD > uvec2; typedef _vec3<DWORD > uvec3; typedef _vec4<DWORD > uvec4;
` without the template the code would be 5x longer